# Hide or remove a tab in tab based application in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, tabs

I am very new to iPhone and Xcode. I am trying to create a tab-based application, in that from the first page, when a button is clicked, I need to remove/hide some of the tabs added in the tab bar.

Can any one help me out please.

Thanks and Regards,
Bala.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you want to remove the fourth tab from the tab bar (tab index == 3). Just modify the tabbar controller's `viewControllers` array accordingly:

```
NSUInteger indexToRemove = 3;
NSMutableArray *controllersToKeep = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.viewControllers];
UIViewController *removedViewController = [[controllersToKeep objectAtIndex:indexToRemove] retain];
[controllersToKeep removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:controllersToKeep animated:YES];
```

Note that if you want to keep the removed/hidden view controller around in the background, it's essential that you retain it before removing it from the tab bar (see line 3).